# How to create a column with a count of rows between two values of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
     'Date': ['1/01/2021','2/01/2021','3/01/2021','4/01/2021','5/01/2021','6/01/2021','7/01/2021','8/01/2021','9/01/2021','10/01/2021','11/01/2021','12/01/2021','13/01/2021',
'14/01/2021','15/01/2021','16/01/2021'],
    'Name': ['Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','John','John','John','John','John','John','John'],
    'Status':['Avaiable','Unavailable','Unavailable','Unavailable','Unavailable','Unavailable','Avaiable','Unavailable','Unavailable','Avaiable','Unavailable','Unavailable'
              ,'Unavailable','Available','Unavailable','Unavailable'],
    'Count' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3]}

              
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%d/%m/%Y')
df
```

How can I create a count of rows since the word `'Available'` appears in the `Status` column.

[image]

Thanks very much!

**EDIT - Extension on Question:**

If i had two start names like the example below where the count starts with either `"First Entry"` or `"Available"`

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
     'Date': ['1/01/2021','2/01/2021','3/01/2021','4/01/2021','5/01/2021','6/01/2021','7/01/2021','8/01/2021','9/01/2021','10/01/2021','11/01/2021','12/01/2021','13/01/2021',
'14/01/2021','15/01/2021','16/01/2021'],
    'Name': ['Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','John','John','John','John','John','John','John'],
    'Status':['First Entry','Unavailable','Available','Unavailable','Unavailable','Unavailable','Available','Unavailable','Unavailable','First Entry','Unavailable','Unavailable'
              ,'Unavailable','Available','Unavailable','Unavailable'],
    'Count' : [1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3]}

              
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%d/%m/%Y')

df
```

[image]

**EXAMPLE 3 - When names are mixed up**

This is an example where names appear throughout the code. The `Count` is what is the expected output is

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
     'Date': ['1/01/2021','2/01/2021','3/01/2021','4/01/2021','5/01/2021','6/01/2021','7/01/2021','8/01/2021','9/01/2021','10/01/2021','11/01/2021','12/01/2021','13/01/2021',
'14/01/2021','15/01/2021','16/01/2021'],
    'Name': ['Joe','John','Joe','Joe','Joe','John','John','Joe','Joe','John','John','John','John','John','John','John'],
    'Status':['First Entry','First Entry','Available','Unavailable','Unavailable','Unavailable','Available','Unavailable','Unavailable','Unavailable','Unavailable','Unavailable'
              ,'Unavailable','Available','Unavailable','Unavailable'],
    'Count' : [1,1,1,2,3,2,1,4,5,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]}

              
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%d/%m/%Y')


df
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If need cumulative counts per `Status` and `Name` groups use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with compare `Status` by `Avaiable`:

```
df['Count1'] = df.groupby(['Name', df['Status'].eq('Avaiable').cumsum()]).cumcount().add(1)
```

---

```
print (df)

         Date  Name       Status  Count  Count1
0  2021-01-01   Joe     Avaiable      1       1
1  2021-01-02   Joe  Unavailable      2       2
2  2021-01-03   Joe  Unavailable      3       3
3  2021-01-04   Joe  Unavailable      4       4
4  2021-01-05   Joe  Unavailable      5       5
5  2021-01-06   Joe  Unavailable      6       6
6  2021-01-07   Joe     Avaiable      1       1
7  2021-01-08   Joe  Unavailable      2       2
8  2021-01-09   Joe  Unavailable      3       3
9  2021-01-10  John     Avaiable      1       1
10 2021-01-11  John  Unavailable      2       2
11 2021-01-12  John  Unavailable      3       3
12 2021-01-13  John  Unavailable      4       4
13 2021-01-14  John     Avaiable      1       1
14 2021-01-15  John  Unavailable      2       2
15 2021-01-16  John  Unavailable      3       3
```

And for second sample:

```
df['Count1'] = df.groupby(['Name', df['Status'].isin(['Avaiable', 'First Entry']).cumsum()]).cumcount().add(1)
```

For third example: Sorting `Name` column first, apply solution and last sorting index for original order:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Name'])
df['Count1'] = df.groupby(['Name', df['Status'].isin(['Available', 'First Entry']).cumsum()]).cumcount().add(1) 
df = df.sort_index() 
print (df)

         Date  Name       Status  Count  Count1
0  2021-01-01   Joe  First Entry      1       1
1  2021-01-02  John  First Entry      1       1
2  2021-01-03   Joe    Available      1       1
3  2021-01-04   Joe  Unavailable      2       2
4  2021-01-05   Joe  Unavailable      3       3
5  2021-01-06  John  Unavailable      2       2
6  2021-01-07  John    Available      1       1
7  2021-01-08   Joe  Unavailable      4       4
8  2021-01-09   Joe  Unavailable      5       5
9  2021-01-10  John  Unavailable      2       2
10 2021-01-11  John  Unavailable      3       3
11 2021-01-12  John  Unavailable      4       4
12 2021-01-13  John  Unavailable      5       5
13 2021-01-14  John    Available      1       1
14 2021-01-15  John  Unavailable      2       2
15 2021-01-16  John  Unavailable      3       3
```

Comment: Brilliant again @jezrael... you are always a massive help, thanks!!

Comment: @SOK - One thing, if `Avaiable` is not first per groups what is output?

Comment: It would say `First Entry`.

Comment: While i think of it, can you specify more than 1 start/end name. For example start count where status either equals `Available` or `First Entry`?

Comment: I will add another example

Comment: addad a 2nd example at the bottom @jezrael

Comment: @SOK -Aded to answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks @jezrael. The 2nd example wasnt working but i realised I've made a spelling error in `Available` in the OP haha

Comment: So i think when the names are mixed up its causing some issues @jezrael. Ill add a third Example along with your code

Comment: @SOK - Added solution

Comment: thanks! so if its orgininally sorted by `Date`, will the sorting by `Name` preserve the `Date` order for each `Name`? If that makes sense

Comment: Great! Thanks again!!